# My ceiling fan has a sporadic loss off power, 1-2 seconds

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

My ceiling fan will briefly (1-2 seconds) lose power then come back on. All wires are connected according to the instructions, but there is a red wire that was not used. Do i need to connect the red wire to something?

Comment: Is there a remote  switching device involved?

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that all the wiring is properly connected? A loose connection could vibrate loose after a while.

Comment: Yeah there's a remote for the fan. I followed all the directions and secured the wires with the wire caps.  I was planning on going back into it and double checking the wires,  but didn't know if there was something else I needed to check for

Comment: What make and model is the fan in question?

Comment: does the fan have a light that works? How many fan speeds are currently working? The red wire is probably a fan speed wire or a wire for the light.

Comment: Its a Hunter, Poplar fan. All the fan speeds work. I just re-checked all the wires and they were all secure.